# status zero results google maps GeocoderStatus

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

We Need Draw Direction between some points in Google maps.We tried but DirectionsStatus comes `"zero results"`.We tried like this

```
 function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
debugger;

  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
   var data = myjson[i];



      waypts.push({
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(myjson[i].Lattitude), parseFloat(myjson[i].Longitude)),
            stopover: true
        });

  }
  debugger;
  console.log(waypts);
 var request = {

      origin:waypts[0].location,
      destination:waypts[waypts.length-1].location,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
debugger;
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  debugger;
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     debugger;
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
    }
  });
}
```

We need Status code `"OK"`.Please help me.tell me What wrong in my code.WE have json and then JSON data pass to Myjson variable.`calcRoute`  method call in button action.

When we print waypoints

```
Array[6]0: Objectlocation: kfD: 78.54940429999999k: 17.4211137__proto__: kfstopover: true__proto__: Object1: Objectlocation: kfstopover: true__proto__: Object2: Objectlocation: kfstopover: true__proto__: Object3: Object4: Object5: Objectlength: 6
```

Comment: what does your `waypts` look like when you alert it (or do `console.log()`)?

Comment: @duncan waypts like this
0: Object
location: kf
D: 78.54940429999999
k: 17.4211137
__proto__: kf
stopover: true
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object

Comment: uh... doesn't look like an array, but it's hard to tell from that comment.  Can you update your answer with exactly what you get if you do console.log() ?

Comment: @duncan Yes we update code jest we print waypoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output, it seems like there are something wrong with your myjson (array?).

Anyway, when I try to reproduce it, it works.

```
  //from how you use your myjson var, I would assume it looks something like this:
  var myjson = [
      { Lattitude: 37.4184, Longitude: -122.0880 },
      { Lattitude: 37.7833, Longitude: -122.4167 },
      { Lattitude: 38.5539, Longitude: -121.7381 }
  ]

  var waypts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
  var data = myjson[i];
      waypts.push({
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(myjson[i].Lattitude), parseFloat(myjson[i].Longitude)),
            stopover: true
        });
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(waypts));

  var request = {
        origin:waypts[0].location,
        destination:waypts[waypts.length-1].location,
        waypoints: waypts.slice(1, waypts.length-1),
        //the example in the documentation does not include the start & end points
        //that might be a problem https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
```

When printing waypoints

```
[{"location":{"k":37.4184,"D":-122.08799999999997},"stopover":true},{"location":{"k":37.7833,"D":-122.41669999999999},"stopover":true},{"location":{"k":38.5539,"D":-121.73810000000003},"stopover":true}]
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the data came from an HTML `li` element, but it came as a String, i.e.

```
coordsData = {
    lat: {
        value: "19.4921383",
        someOtherProperties: {}
    },
    lng: {
        value: "-99.04651999999999",
        someOtherProperties: {}
    }
}
```

So, I had to convert those values like:

```
var myCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coordsData.lat.value), parseFloat(coordsData.lng.value))
```

Just in case someone comes across the same issue.